# What image formats support indexed color palettes with more than 256 colors?

Tags: color, image

I've been reading up on images with indexed color, and while most indexed image formats are limited to 256 colors, there are apparently image formats that support larger palettes.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_color)

> Indexed color images with palette sizes beyond 256 entries are rare

I did some extra searching, but I can't seem to find any clear list or mention of specific image formats that support larger color palettes.

Comment: I don't know of any per se, but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_16-bit_computer_color_palettes#Amiga_OCS *suggests* that the Amiga had a 12bit encoding that could be changed, so perhaps that might be a starting point?